# Chrome not returning hash value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, hash

I'm using the following snippet if jQuery JavaScript to return a hash value at the end of a URL. It works perfectly in FF but the alert on line 4 returns empty in Chrome.

Seems like the `window.location.hash.substring(1)` line does not work. I have also tried `window.location.hash.replace("#", "");`

```
// Map Clicks
$("#tab2.tab_content #map").delayed('click', 500, function() {
    state = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    alert(state);
    jsonLink = 'http://ml.uscm.org/ministries.json?state=' + state + '&active=true&callback=?';
    getMapResults();
    return false;
});
```

What's the trick to retrieving a hash value from the URL in Chrome?

The URL is built like this :

```
http://www.ourdomain.com/thispage.html#IL
```

Where IL is a two letter abbreviation for a state. I want to get the "IL".

I have a working demo here:

http://richcoy.com/locator/index2.html

Click on the Search by State tab in Chrome then click on a state and you'll see the issue. The browser shows that the url that it wants to go to is built correctly. –

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example, or working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) where we can take a look at the issue?

Comment: I've updated the question to include more info.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6SoM9.png ) . Also -- what is `delayed` ?

Comment: Delayed is a jquery plugin that slows down the processing of the click a little so that FF has time to update the URL, otherwise it get's processed before the URL has changed to the new hash. That's partly why I don't have a  jsfiddle, so many dependent files. I've narrowed the problem down to this snippet and hoped that would be enough to find an answer.

Comment: @RichCoy Anyway it does work in chrome. as you can see

Comment: Has the hash actually changed in the URL? Where is your code to do that? And is it delayed as well?

Comment: I have a working demo here: 

http://richcoy.com/locator/index2.html 

Click on the Search by State tab in Chrome then click on a state and you'll see the issue. The browser shows that the url that it wants to go to is built correctly.

Comment: I might be wrong, but when you return false from anchor's click event, it should not change the hash...

Comment: Your `window.location` at the time of click is `http://richcoy.com/locator/index2.html` - hence no hash

Comment: @RichCoy Do you really want to use hash? You can use a simpler way to get the clicked state by using jQuery `.attr('href').substring(1)` or something like `.data('state')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate all the help and suggestions.

The answer to the question ended up that I needed to make the paths for the URLs absolute, not relative.

So as an example, a line in the JavaScript went from:

```
"AL": {tooltip: 'Alabama', attr: {fill: '#F9B625', href: '#AL'}},
```

To:

```
"AL": {tooltip: 'Alabama', attr: {fill: '#F9B625', href: 'http://richcoy.com/locator/index2.html#AL'}},
```

Once I changed this for all 50 states a click on the map pulled the data from the jasonp feed correctly and displayed it on the page in Chrome, as well as in Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to try this instead:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    console.log(window.location.hash.substring(1));
});
```

The click event triggers before the hashchange event so you can't rely on your map click implement (even if you delayed it).

Supported browsers list for hashchange: http://caniuse.com/hashchange

In case you don't have to use hash, here is a simpler solution:

```
$("#tab2.tab_content #map a").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('href').substring(1));
});
```

In summary, you shouldn't use any kind of delayed methods.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the problem quite apparent, or am I being silly? In the following function, you handle the clicks on the map, you listen to `click`, delay them by `500ms` and then run through your function.

```
$("#tab2.tab_content #map").delayed('click', 500, function() {
  state = window.location.hash.substring(1);
  alert(state);
  jsonLink = 'http://ml.uscm.org/ministries.json?state=' + state + '&active=true&callback=?';
  getMapResults();
  return false;
});
```

But at the point where you `alert` your `state`, it's empty because you haven't yet set it. Your `return false;` will also stop the browser from changing the hash.

Try this function, and I bet you'll get something:

```
$("#tab2.tab_content #map").delayed('click', 500, function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    var state = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    alert(state);
    jsonLink = 'http://ml.uscm.org/ministries.json?state=' + state + '&active=true&callback=?';
    getMapResults();
  }, 500);
});
```

A quick way to get it working would be to do the following:

```
$("#tab2.tab_content #map a").delayed('click', 500, function(e) {
  state = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');
  alert(state);
});
```

you could then easily change the hash manually by also adding this into the callback:

```
window.location.hash = state;
```

but your real issue is that your `a` (anchors) aren't changing the hash themselves, which makes it seem like there is somewhere in your code that's stopping it.

Comment: This creates an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: state is not defined

Comment: @RichCoy, see my edit. This is only to test that this is the issue, you should read and understand the issue that I raised to begin with and play around with it. Try this and see what happens

Comment: I'm trying to understand, still pretty new to jQuery. It has taken me weeks just to get this far. Your updated code still says state is undefined though it seems like it is on the line above the alert. I've updated the demo to use your code.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, only can set hash will anchor, eg:

```
<a href="#exemplo" />
```

If you do this by setting a hash of another element, try to exchange it for an anchor.

in this link you see the chrome accepts the hash property:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

Comment: [You can set the hash the same way as in other browsers.](http://jsfiddle.net/jbK67/)

Answer (score 0):

How about you modify your code a bit,

```
$("#tab2.tab_content #map a").click(function(){
 console.log($(this).attr("href"));//this outputs the value to the console
});
```

this will output #CA for California

i.e.

```
$("#tab2.tab_content #map a").delayed('click', 500, function() {

    //state = window.location.hash.substring(1);
state = $(this).attr("href").substring(1);
        alert(state);
    jsonLink = 'http://ml.uscm.org/ministries.json?state=' + state + '&active=true&callback=?';
    getMapResults();
    return false;
    });
```

In your code if you place a breakpoint (ln36 `state = window.location.hash.substring(1);`) when the event is fired, the window has not yet changed location so the hash does not exist at that point.

Answer (score 0):

When I check in Chrome's inspector, it appears that your anchors uses `href` from a different namespace, which isn't declared in your `svg` tag.

```
<a xlink:href="#SD">
```

Firefox seems fine with that, but Chrome doesn't seems to guess how to interpret this correctly.

From this [link](https://jwatt.org/svg/authoring/), I've found:

> **Bind the required namespaces**
>
> SVG is a namespaced XML dialect, and as a consequence all the XML
>   dialects used in your SVG documents must be bound to their namespace
>   as specified in the Namespaces in XML recommendation. It is sensible
>   to bind the SVG and **XLink namespaces** at a minimum, and possibly also
>   the XML Events namespace.

So, try to add `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` to your SVG tag.

### Edit

As I can see in the image you posted, you declared `xmlns:xlink` well in your .svg. But in the rendered page by Chrome, there is no such thing!

Here's what I see (Chrome 30) :

```
<svg height="100%" version="1.1" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 165 96" preserveAspectRatio="meet" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
```

From here, it's beyond my knowledge: can some namespace for a tag be stored somewhere else by the browser? I've searched through its DOM properties, can't find it.

Another clue: you declared `xmlns:svg` too.

Quoted from the former link:

> Be careful not to type xmlns:svg instead of just xmlns when you bind
>   the SVG namespace. This is an easy mistake to make, but one that can
>   break everything. Instead of making SVG the default namespace, it
>   binds it to the namespace prefix 'svg', and this is almost certainly
>   not what you want to do in an SVG file. A standards compliant browser
>   will then fail to recognise any tags and attributes that don't have an
>   explicit namespace prefix (probably most if not all of them) and fail
>   to render your document as SVG.

[Additional doc about xlink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink%3ahref)

Comment: @RichCoy Are you sure? I see `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`, but not the `xlink` one.

Comment: Well, call me crazy, but at the time I wrote this, I didn't see it in your example page. 

Plus, even if I'm blind, it must be an attribute of the `svg` tag, not on another line.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing: http://richcoy.com/locator/images/svgtag.png

Comment: @RichCoy Alright... But Chrome doesn't keep all these attributes. See my edited post

Answer (score 0):

```
var myURL = document.URL; //example http://www.ourdomain.com/thispage.html#IL
var getTheMagicWord = myURL.split("#");
console.log(getTheMagicWord[1]); //logs IL
```